# Visual Studio 2022 font awful in one project but not the other

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have been noticing the font is horrible in VS 2022 for a while.  I don't think it started off that way, but at some point I did a phunky key combination I think by mistake and I think I did something inadertantly.

Anyway I am trying to solve a code problem in a book example I am following.  So I downloaded the code from github and opened up his code in the solution in VS 2022 to compare his code to mine side by side and lord behold his font is perfect!  His solution and project have the correct code but it's hosted on my computer in my VS 2022 install so what gives?

This is what it looks like side by side.

I tried comparing the settings under Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors for both Solutions but the settings are the same since they are both for my install.  I am totally confused.  How can I get the font for my projects looking like the one on the right again.  This is maddening.

[image]

This is what the settings look like for each side.  They are the same.  I clicked Use Defaults on the left.  But I have not restarted VS yet.  Now I am nervous about how that will turn out.

[image]

Comment: Look the same to me.

Comment: The left hand code is displayed in Cascadia Code, the right hand code in Consolas. The font setting seems to persist.

Comment: No, the font on the right is more square which is what I want. The font on the left is more curvy.